# Ionic 2 Native Camera - Limit duration of video capturing

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using Ionic 2 Native to capture video in my app, and I need to limit the duration of the video to a few seconds.

Is this possible using Ionic Native? if not, is it possible using other Cordova plugins?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Media Capture](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/#CaptureVideoOptions) plugin from Ionic Native, using the `duration` property to handle that.

```
MediaCapture.captureVideo({ limit: 1, duration: 20 })...
```

In that case, the maximum duration of the video will be **20** seconds.

Comment: @NicholasFrancis could you please add some more details to your comment? I've used this feature on Android and worked properly.

Comment: i added the above options, when i start recording, the video doesnt stop at 20 seconds, the video goes on untill manually stopped